# $R$ ring without identity generated by an element

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ a commutative ring without unity and we suppose that exist $a\in R$ such that:
$$R=\{ar+na\;|\;r\in R,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}=(a).$$
We observe that the principal generated ideal $(a^2)=\{a^2r+na^2\;|\;r\in R,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a proper ideal of $R$, in fact $a\in(a)$, but $a\notin(a^2)$. Indedd, observe that, were $a$ in $(a^2)$, we could write $a=a^2\overline{r}+\overline{n}a^2$ and at this point, if we define $e=a\overline{r}+\overline{n}a$, $e$ would a multiplicative identity for $R$. For to prove this I take $r_1\in R$ and after the calculation I get that $$er=e^2r.$$

A this point, can I conclude that $er=r$ even if $R$ is not a integral domain?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you want to use $r_1$?  What are the bars in $\bar r$ and $\bar n$ supposed to mean? just $\bar r\in R$ and $\bar n \in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: I was wrong to write $e$, sorry

Comment: $r_1$ is a specific element of $R$ and $\overline{r}$ and $\overline{n}$ are the specific element which exist in conseguence to the fact that $a\in (a^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this logic is incorrect.

Take, for example, any boolean ring without identity. In that case, $(a)=(a^2)$ for every $a$, but there is no identity.

From $a=a^2r+na^2=e$, it simply does not follow that $e$ is an identity for the ring. (Edit: this has since been corrected in the post. The following comment confirms what the OP says.)

It is true, though, if you assume $R$ is a domain that the existence of a single $a\neq 0$ such that $a\in (a^2)$ does imply $ar+an$ is the identity for the ring. It's not true otherwise, as the example I gave shows.

Comment: Sorry! I was wrong to write $e$....

Comment: Now, I correct.

Comment: Ok, but my book conclude saying that $e$ is a identity for $R$, but  it does not specify if $R$ is a integral domain....

Comment: Perhaps we can show otherwise that $e$ is identity without arriving at that equality?

Comment: @JackJ. The counterexample I gave shows that it is possible for $(a)=(a^2)$ for all $a$, and yet there is no identity.  So it would be a waste of time to attempt a proof...  The situation is as I say in the last paragraph.